# How to test performance of software AG - Web methods implementation?

Tags: performance, architecture, esb, webmethods

I have a requirement to test the performance of an ESB implementation done using software SG - web methods 9.5.

Please let me know the tools that can be used and the approach to be followed for testing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to performance test webMethods Integration Server a couple of years ago.

I set up requests, number of clients etc in SoapUI that represented different scenarios of usage in the live system.

After the tests I exported data from SoapUI, wrote some scripts to analyze it and used Excel to present it in a pretty way.

Since you don't specify exactly what kind of performance test you want to run this may or may not work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide any suggestions because little is known from your "ESB implementation" and little is known from the performance requirements. For example, from which point in your architecture do you want to test performance.

As suggested by ellak, using SOAPUI is an option if your "ESB implementation" exposes a web services and if you want to start load testing at the ESB level.

If you want better advice then you need to provide more information.